# How can I open excel file through ride in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How can I open excel file through ride in robot framework. I am trying to Open Excel keyword but I am keep getting error "No such file or directory".

Comment: If you get "no such file or directory" then you are giving it a path that doesn't exist. The error message is not lying to you.

Comment: May I know what will be the exact path? Where can I put excel file? I mean on desktop or document folder?

Comment: The only person that can answer what the path is is you. We have no way of knowing. It's on your filesytem somewhere. You can put the file anywhere you want. Some people put test data in the same folder as the test, others create a dedicated test folder. It's up to you.

Comment: you are using wrong path , you should double check on it agian .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my sample code below :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           ExcelLibrary
*** Variables ***
${path_excel}    res/my_excel_file.xls

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Excel     ${path_excel}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, another option if you prefer not to use a variable for the excel file -> Just store the excel file in the same folder as your project and one important thing to mention is that RIDE - Robot Framework does not support excel files that have the extension of .xlsx, if your excel file is .xlsx format, you will need to open it in excel and do a file save as .xls which is the older format.  Once you do this and store the .xls file to your project folder (Which is usually in C:\Python27\Scripts\ProjectFolderName) you can use the following just replace the test.xls with the name of your .xls file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    ExcelLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Excel Current Directory     test.xls
```