# How to open an Excel

Tags: excel, robotframework

I am trying to open a Excel using Robot Framework, but I am get an error "No keyword with name 'Open Excel' found."

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong..

Thanks in Advance

My code :

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           ExcelLibrary

*** Variables ***

${Excel_File_Path}  C:\TesteAA\Outros PDF\


*** Test Cases ***

Excel 
    Open Excel    ${Excel_File_Path}ClientesDIgiPlay.xlsx

    ${Names}=      Get Sheet Names
```

[image]

Comment: Check it out Edu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511733/how-can-i-open-excel-file-through-ride-in-robot-framework Un saludo.

Comment: Hy Elias.. I did it but the problem is still there.. I added a picture of my Robot.

Comment: The error message and the code you've included in your question are different. Please provide actual code that causes the error.

Comment: The error message seems to be telling you exactly what's wrong. It's saying there is no keyword named `Open Excel Current Directory`. Looking at the documentation for [ExcelLibrary](https://rawgit.com/peterservice-rnd/robotframework-excellib/master/docs/ExcelLibrary.html) I see no keyword by that name.

Comment: Thank you  Bryan... based on your comment I could undestand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "Open Excel Document" to fix your issue and not "Open Excel", provided you follow the steps mentioned below.

install robotframework-excellib module using pip as shown below,

```
pip install robotframework-excellib
```

Reading Excel

https://rawgit.com/peterservice-rnd/robotframework-excellib/master/docs/ExcelLibrary.html

sample excel -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FCwGutdcuQCTuGHfNi4WSV37VZLgmDw1ymUOr7mCO6g/edit?usp=sharing

Example:-

```
sample.robot


*** Settings ***
Library    ExcelLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Check created excel doc
        Open Excel Document     filename=file1.xlsx     doc_id=doc1
        ${a1}=  Read Excel Cell row_num=1       col_num=1
        Should Be Equal As Strings      ${a1}   Hello
        Close All Excel Documents



(rf1) 08:55 PM##~/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog::>robot sample.robot 
==============================================================================
Sample                                                                        
==============================================================================
Check created excel doc                                               | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sample                                                                | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/output.xml
Log:     /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/log.html
Report:  /Users/apachemain/bins/projects/PycharmProjects/blog/report.html
```